# Created TableView forgets a variable from initialization until table creation

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to create a TableView in a TableViewController and initialize it with a dic. The number of items in the dic should determine the number of rows of my TableView. In the Initializer, I display it's count and getting: "resource table created with 8 entries." but when the Table built and the method 'numberOfRowsInSection' is called it returns "Now: 0 entries."

I tried making the dictionary static with no success and also tried "@property(strong,nonatomic,retain)". How can I make the instance not to forget it's content?

edit: moved here: [Variable set in the TableView initializer is forgotten when numberOfRowsInSection is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675288)
edit 2: Problem solved in the already linked thread, so is this one.

Relevant code snipplets:

```
//  somewhere in ViewController.m:
...
resourceTableViewController = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithDictionary:dictionary];


//  ResourcesTableViewController.h:

@interface ResourcesTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain)NSDictionary *resourcesAsDictionary;
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic;

//  ResourcesTableViewController.m:

- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic {
    if (self = [super init])
        [self setResourcesAsDictionary:dic];
    NSLog(@"resource table created with %i entries.",[_resourcesAsDictionary count]);
    return self;
}

...

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSLog(@"Now: %i entries.",[_resourcesAsDictionary count]);
    return [_resourcesAsDictionary count];
}
```

Comment: check that resourcesAsDictionary has memory. you may need to alloc memory to that dictonary in .m file

Comment: Checked and yes, I forgot it. I changed the initializer to: "resourcesAsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];" but it's still the same error. :-/

Comment: The code you've posted looks like it should work, so there must be something else in your implementation causing a problem.  Are there other references to _resourcesAsDictionary in your code?

Comment: @CharlesA. This question is 3 years old.  I doubt the OP has been stuck for that length of time.

Comment: @trojanfoe Looks like someone edited it, so it came up at the top of the interesting questions feed.