# Variable set in the TableView initializer is forgotten when numberOfRowsInSection is called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm using Xcode 4.5 with ARC to create a UITableViewController class and I want to initialize it with a NSDictionary. In its initializer the created [resourcesAsDictionary count] is returning some proper value but later on when I'm pressing a button in my main view and the table is built according to the number of entries of the NSDictionary I initialized the class with, the NSDictionary is always empty and [resourcesAsDictionary count] returns 0.
I assume this has to do with ARC? If I would turn that off, I could retain that variable? But there has to be a way do get this WITH ARC?)
The relevant code:

edit: I already changed the code according to the help I received.
edit2: Since I was able to narrow the problem down and this was a bit confusing and far to much to read in I created a new topic: [ViewController class creates new instance when creating view, but it should use an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683486)
edit 3: Problem solved in the already linked thread, so is this one.

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/NSJSONSerialization.h>
#import <Foundation/NSXMLParser.h>
#import "ResourcesTableViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
// Note: this <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> is NOT related to the TableViewController. My ViewController has another TableView.
NSDictionary *parsedResponseAsDictionary;
ResourcesTableViewController *resourceTableViewController;
...
}
...
```

Somewhere in ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    parsedResponseAsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
}
...
-   (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)_bodyData {
    parsedResponseAsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:bodyData options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&err];
    ... // putting found keys as entries in an array foundResources
    if ([foundResources count] > 0) {
        resourceTableViewController = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        [resourceTableViewController setResourcesAsDictionary:parsedResponseAsDictionary];
        NSLog(@"Delivered %i entries.",[[resourceTableViewController resourcesAsDictionary] count]);
        // TableView can be built: enable "Show Resources" button
        [_showResourcesButton setAlpha:1];
        [_showResourcesButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
...
// Output:
// REST Analyzer[1259:c07] Delivered 8 entries.
// REST Analyzer[1259:c07] viewWillAppear: (null)
// REST Analyzer[1259:c07] Now: 0 entries.
```

ResourcesTableViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ResourcesTableViewController : UITableViewController {
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *resourcesAsDictionary;

@end
```

ResourcesTableViewController.m:

```
#import "ResourcesTableViewController.h"

@implementation ResourcesTableViewController

// - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dic {
//    if (self = [super init])
//        resourcesAsDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:dic];
//    NSLog(@"resource table created with %i entries.",[resourcesAsDictionary count]);
//    return self;
// }

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear: %@", self.resourcesAsDictionary);
    // (null) is returned here.
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Now: %i entries.",[self.resourcesAsDictionary count]);
    return [self.resourcesAsDictionary count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    // UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2
                                      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"Cell";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Description";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling initWithDictionary and when tableview is loading? Do you have parent child relationship? By default resourcesAsDictionary variable is strong so it should be retained anyway! Can you give more info how you have implemented this. Can you try declaring resourcesAsDictionary as @property(nonatomic, strong) and see it that works. You will need to use self.resourcesAsDictionary then.

Comment: @applefreak: I'm calling initWithDictionary somewhere in my ViewController.m after receiving a HTTP response and found some resources in it. I filled them in a dictionary and want to initialize the new class with it. Declaring it as property was the solution I tried in the answer under this, it doesn't work (yet?). I don't exactly what you mean with parent child relationship? my ViewController that calls the TableViewController class doesn't have such a relationship, no.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake on the viewWillAppear...  The function is - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated this will autocomplete though so just use the autocomplete version when you type - (void)viewWillAp...

Comment: @Fogmeister: Not your mistake if I'm too inattentive to have a look at the autocompletion. Should have known that by now. :-/ Now it is returning (null) for self.resourcesAsDictionary in viewWillAppear.

Comment: The part where I am creating the TableView class is somewhere after parsing a HTTP response. The pushView is implemented with storyboard as popover when clicking the button. The output is: "Delivered 8 entries." after parsing the response and as soon as I click the button, it will add "viewWillAppear: (null)" and "Now: 0 entries." in that order.

Comment: I printed the memory address of my class just after the call as <ResourcesTableViewController: 0x8179bd0>, after I called the view I let viewDidLoad return it's "self" address as <ResourcesTableViewController: 0x82c26a0>. It's different, so when the new View is called, it obviously creates a new instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ViewController class creates new instance when creating view, but it should use an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683486/viewcontroller-class-creates-new-instance-when-creating-view-but-it-should-use)

Answer (score 1):

I would change this in a couple of ways...

Remove the iVar for resourcesAsDictionary and set it as a property instead.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *resourcesAsDictionary;
```

Then I'd change the initialisation by removing your init method and using this property instead.

In the viewController that pushes on to this controller (i.e. where you call the initWithDictionary)...

Instead of initWithDictionary have...

```
ResourcesTableViewController *tvc = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:<whicheverstyleyouneed>];
```

Then set the property...

```
tvc.resourcesAsDictionary = mySourceDictionary;
```

Then push the TVC...

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:tic animated:YES];
```

...or however you are pushing this to the screen.

Finally you'll need to change your numberOfRows... code to...

```
return [self.resourcesAsDictionary count];
```

The would be my approach and it means you don't have to override the init of the UITableViewController class.

By having the strong property you are ensuring it will stay around for the life of the owning object.  And by not overriding the init you ensure that you're not missing out on any code that gets called in initWithStyle...

If this doesn't work then I can only think that there is something not right with the way you are creating the dictionary in the first place.

In the - (void)viewWillAppear... function tell me the output of...

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.resourcesAsDictionary);
```

Comment: I tried your advice and changed my code like this:

// ResourcesTableViewController.h:

`code`#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface ResourcesTableViewController : UITableViewController {

    }

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *resourcesAsDictionary;

    @end

Comment: // calling ViewController.m class:

`code`    resourceTableViewController = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [resourceTableViewController setResourcesAsDictionary:parsedResponseAsDictionary];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:resourceTableViewController animated:YES];`code`

But the result is the same, numberOfRowsInSection returns 0 for a non-empty dictionary.

Comment: How can I format code snipplets the right way in a comment? ._.

Comment: numberIfRowsInSection now returns [self.resourcesAsDictionary count] but still always 0. :-(
in my ViewController.m I'm calling right after the push: NSLog(@"%i",[[resourceTableViewController resourcesAsDictionary]count]); with the output "8", whereas in my numberOfRowsInSection NSLog(@"%i",[self.resourcesAsDictionary count]); is giving my still 0. :-(

Comment: I created the function:
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    NSLog(@"viewWillAppear: %@", self.resourcesAsDictionary);
} But it's never called? :-/

Comment: Ah, the function is... - (void)viewWillAppearAnimated:(BOOL)animated.  Without seeing more code I'm not able to help any further sorry. This should work as I have explained.

Comment: Changed it like that and is still not called. What code do you need to see? What is relevant for you? I extend my post to the full ResourcesTableViewController.m... I don't think the ViewController.m is relevant but the lines this class is calling?

Comment: I have to leave now for about 2 - 3 hours. I would be certainly happy to continue our discussion then. ^_^

Comment: Will take a look when I get home.

Comment: Thank you. I tried a bit and thought I may have an idea but I still get down to: I don't have a clue. After creation I can access the NSDictionary from the calling class and it exists and is not empty. When the view appears the NSDictionary is already (null). :-(

Comment: Since I was able to narrow the problem down and this was a bit confusing and far to much to read in I created a new topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683486 Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you had said (at any point throughout this whole thing) that you were using Storyboards it would have been a lot easier to help. Down voted.

Comment: Do you think I did that on purpose? ._.' I said that I'm new to XCode and Objective-C and I really did NOT suspected that it could have something to do with using the storyboard. I thought it would be quite normal to use it. :-/ Didn't yet know it while writing the other question. It was coincidence that I mentioned it there and not here. I noticed that it makes a difference when I read that the storyboard creates his own instance besides the code who creates another. If you have to vote me down for my ignorance so shall it be. Sorry anyway and honestly thank you for your time though. :-/