# ViewController class creates new instance when creating view, but it should use an existing one

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm creating a TableViewController in a class named ResourcesTableViewController. I'm creating the class with:

ViewController.h:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    ResourcesTableViewController *resourceTableViewController;
```

ViewController.m:

```
resourceTableViewController = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[resourceTableViewController setTableViewObject:localObject];
```

Now I can work with it and I can call

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@",resourceTableViewController,[resourceTableViewController tableViewObject]);
```

at several parts in my ViewController.m with (as expected) the same output

```
<ResourcesTableViewController: 0x749f1c0> tableViewObjectContent
```

. For switching on the new TableView I created in the storyboard a button with the popover to the new view (as triggered segue). But as soon as the button is pressed and the view shall appear, it creates a new instance. Curiously I put in the viewDidLoad of my class ResourcesTableViewController:

```
NSLog(@"viewDidLoad: %@: %@", self, self.tableViewObject);
```

and it is returning

```
<ResourcesTableViewController: 0x74bbcd0>: (null)
```

. Another memory adress, another instance. Not the instance I worked with before and absolutely not the instance to which I gave that tableViewOject.
How can I call the view from that instance belonging to the resourceTableViewController I created and worked with? I still can access that "old" instance through communicating with the object resourceTableViewController but the created view is another one of that type that certainly doesn't make use from the object I gave to the first one.

Comment: Did you also create a table view controller in your storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I did. I created a Table View Controller and properly assigned it to my class ResourcesTableViewController.

Comment: Can't I make this view some kind of static?

Comment: I think your problem is creating the controller both in code and in the storyboard, that's why you get 2 different instances. I'm not really sure how to fix it without knowing more about what you're trying to do. For instance, what do you mean by "For switching on the new TableView"?

Comment: I don't think I'm creating the controller both in code and in the storyboard, I just created the class, then created the controller in storyboard and assigned it to the class. So I used the "ResourcesTableViewController *resourceTableViewController;" in my ViewController.h to access this storyboard created Table View Controller. Isn't this how it should be? (Yes, I'm pretty new in XCode, writing my first App, but this already is a bachelor's thesis, so I need to get this done.) More code you see on my question that brought me to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675288

Comment: With "switching on the new TableView" I just meant to make the table view appear. Sorry if I sometimes have a sloppy grammar, I'm no native speaker. ^^' Do you mean the part in my ViewController.m where I create my instance with "resourceTableViewController = [[ResourcesTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];"? And the click on my button would be the call of the already existing instance? What would be the "clean" way of accessing the Table View Controller already created in storyboard instead of allocating and initializing a new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to show the table view depends on how you want to show it, and what is on the screen before that. Normally, you would use a segue to transition from the current controller (the one that you button is in) to the table view. To do that you could use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: where the identifier parameter is a name you give to the segue in IB. But you can do it with no code at all by control dragging from the button in your one view to the table view controller's view and choosing modal for the type of segue -- then, a button click will cause that table view to appear on screen.

You shouldn't alloc init it at all in your code if you're using a storyboard -- the segue instantiates the new view controller for you.

Comment: Yes, but this is not the problem. The new View DOES appear, but it's not that one I created and communicated in my ViewController.m with. I liked your motivation that I could be creating two instances and it's right - I now read that the storyboard creates its own instance when showing the view.

Comment: I'm actually trying to access this instance with "UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];" and "resourcesTableViewController = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:resourcesTableViewControllerID];" after setting the "Storyboard ID" of the Table View Controller to "resourcesTableViewControllerID". I'm now still getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier 'resourcesTableViewControllerID'" that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: Why do you want to access the instance?  I don't know what you're trying to do with that. You should get rid of the code where you instantiate the table view controller, you don't need it.

Comment: Well, the point is I want to create a Table View with a specified number of rows. I'm working with HTTP requests/responses in my main view. When I receive a response, I'm parsing it for valid resources which I store in a dictionary. After that, I want to access the table view instance and deliver the dictionary so when this specific instance is called (by pressing the button) has access to this dictionary and can create it's table with the appropriate number of cells and fill it with the dictionary entries.

Comment: I forgot the @""... So the right code should be: UIStoryboard *storybord = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; resourceTableViewController = [storybord instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resourcesTableViewControllerID"]; But it still creates the new instance instead of accessing the existing. It's exasperating. :-(

Comment: Then you need to override prepareForSegue:sender: in the class that has the button. You can access the controller you're presenting with segue.destinationViewController. You can use that reference to pass any information you need to set it up.

Comment: You shouldn't have 2 instances -- get rid of the one you create in the code, then you won't have that problem!!

Comment: Yes, I recognised that already. That's because I wanted to access the storyboard one and that's exactly what you helped me with. Man, I love you. prepareForSegue:sender finally worked. Thank you very very much. <3